# After create setup.exe using exe4j file writing prosses not working

Tags: java, jar, file-writing, exe4j

I want to create log file and write some text to that file in java .I completed that task.when run jar file this code working well.but after create setup.exe using exe4j file  writing process not working.any one know how to do this?

**this is how I get path of jar file located directory**

```
File f = null;

 public String baseUrl() {
        try {
            if (f == null) {
                f = new File(Register.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getRawPath());
            }
            String path = f.getParent();
            return path;
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

**This is my log file creating process**

```
    try {
    src.Log lg = new src.Log();
        lg.setAction(action);
        lg.setUserName(userName);
        lg.setDescription(description);
        lg.setTime(date);
        lg.setSyncPath(syncPath);
        lg.setMethod(method);

        String url = baseUrl();
        System.out.println(baseUrl());
        String directoryName = url + "/ResFile";

        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdir();

        }

        File log = new File(directoryName + "/log.txt");

            if (log.exists() == false) {
                log.createNewFile();
            }
            try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(log, true))) {
                out.append(lg.toString());
            }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "JAR in EXE" mode, your log file will end up in a temporary directory, because that's where the JAR files are extracted at run time.

To get the directory where the executable is located, you can use

```
System.getProperty("install4j.exeDir")
```

Comment: Hi,I use 
System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\AppData"
now my file create on AppData folder.